# Rerun Cucumber step only in case of specific failure

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, selenium, cucumber

Running Cucumber in CircleCI with Selenium sometimes the tests fail due to CircleCI's performance. A common failure is a `Net::ReadTimeout` error, which never seems to happen locally. I want to rescue the steps from that error and try them again, but I do *not* want to rerun all failed tests.

I could put build a rescue into the specific step(s) that seem to trigger this error, but ideally I would be able to provide Cucumber a list of errors that it rescues once or twice, to rerun that step, before finally letting the error pass through.

Something like:

```
# support/env.rb
Cucumber.retry_errors = {
  # error => number of retries
  "Net::ReadTimeoutError" => 2
}
```

Does anything like that exist?

Answer (score 1):

I know this doesn't specifically catch retries only of a specific class, but there does exist a clean way to do this in cucumber now, especially since this result comes up in Google when searching for "rerun cucumber"

In your cucumber.yml file, you can do something like this now:

```
<%
std_opts = "--format #{ENV['CUCUMBER_FORMAT'] || 'pretty'} --strict --tags 'not @wip'"
std_opts_with_retry = "#{std_opts} --no-strict-flaky --retry 3"
%>
default: <%= std_opts_with_retry %> features
```

There was a big philosophical debate about whether or not a "flaky" test should be considered a fail.  It was agreed if "--strict" is passed, the default should be that "flaky" tests (aka: tests that fail on the first run and pass on a following run) fail the run.  So in order to get flaky tests to not "fail" your test run, you can pass the additional `--no-strict-flaky` along with the `--retry 3` option and now any tests that may sometimes take a variable amount of time on your CI platform won't require a rebuild of the entire commit.

One thing to note when doing this: in general, I'd advise bumping your timeout back down to a reasonable limit where the majority of tests can pass without needing a long wait, although I understand in this case it's to accommodate longer compile times.

Answer (score 0):

I would be surprised if you found something like you are looking for in Cucumber.

Re-running a failing step just to make really sure that it is an actual failure and not just a random network glitch is, from my perspective, solving the wrong issue.

My approach would be see if the verification you are looking for is possible to do without a network. I might also consider using other tooling than Cucumber if I really must re-run a few times to make sure an error really is an error. This would, however, lead me down another rabbit hole. How many times should you run, what is the threshold? Should three out of five executions pass for you to declare a passing test? It gets ugly very fast in my eyes.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this issue is that Selenium takes took long the compile the assets on the first test. Subsequent tests use the compiled assets and do not have an issue. After viewing [this Github issue](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara/issues/1305) I upped the timeout limit for Selenium.

```
Capybara.register_driver :chrome do |app|
  http_client = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Http::Default.new
  http_client.timeout = 120 # default is 60 seconds
  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, browser: :chrome, http_client: http_client)
end
```